# MSXML SelectSingleNode returning all values

Tags: xml, vba, msxml, selectsinglenode

When running this command:

```
objDoc.SelectSingleNode ("//ProfileSettings/Form[@name='frmViewMailMessages']/Control[@name='subMailMessages']/Height")
```

With objDoc's XML being:

```
<ProfileSettings>
    <Form name="frmViewMailMessages">
        <Control name="subMailMessages">
            <Height>4175</Height>
        </Control>
        <Control name="subMailMessage">
            <Height>4500</Height>
            <Top>3975</Top>
        </Control>
    </Form>
</ProfileSettings>
```

objDoc.Text returns a string containing all values appended:

```
417545003975
```

I'm trying to only receive the value 4175 from frmViewMailMessages->subMailMessages->Height

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i know why .... you are using wrong object. Instead of using the `objDoc`, you need to set this into a `Node` and then retrieve the value. Something like the below

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\Pankaj\Desktop\test.xml")

Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ProfileSettings/Form[@name='frmViewMailMessages']/Control[@name='subMailMessages']/Height")
msgbox nodeXML.Text
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it like this:
Set nodeXML = objDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ProfileSettings/Form[@name='" & frm.NAME & "']/Control[@name='" & ControlName & "']/" & Property)
MsgBox nodeXML.Text